# Unable to load asset flutter ( not assets is a saved file )

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

when user take photo or video i saved this file to applicationfolder
when i try to access with xcode to saved folder i can see the image or video without problem.

after taking and saving this photo the app can reach the image or video and i can show it in my app

but after a while or when i closed and re-open the phone this file can not be access
but if i want to show in application folder which opens with xcode i can show the file

here is my save image code

```
   Future<void> saveFile(BuildContext context, int fileType,
          {Function(String path) onComplete}) async {
        File file = await Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => fileType == 0 ? Camera() : Video()));
        if (file != null) {
          var savedFile = await getNewFile(file, fileType);
    
          if (fileType == 0) {
            GallerySaver.saveImage(savedFile.path).then((result) async {
              if (result)
                onComplete(savedFile.path);
              else
                onComplete("");
            });
          } else {
            GallerySaver.saveVideo(savedFile.path).then((result) async {
              if (result)
                onComplete(savedFile.path);
              else
                onComplete("");
            });
          }
        } else {
          onComplete("");
        }   }

Future<File> getNewFile(File file, int fileType) async {
    final Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var fileName = UniqueKey()
            .toString()
            .replaceAll("[", "")
            .replaceAll("]", "")
            .replaceAll("#", "") +
        (fileType == 0 ? ".png" : ".mp4");

    return await file.copy('${path.path}/$fileName');
  }
```

**YOU GOT THE ERROR B4A3B.MP4 NOT FOUND BUT ITS ALREADY IN THE PATH**

[image]

**ITS RIGHT BOTTOM OF IMAGE YOU CAN LOOK**

[image]

STARTLY ITS LOADING WITHOUT PROBLEM BUT AFTER A WHILE ITS NOT SHOWING IN MY APP

Comment: did add the file in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: no this is not a asset file this is saved image file to phone application folder

Comment: please post the whole error from the console, the exception its throwing

Comment: error is : unable to load assets ..../documents/b4a3b.mp3

Comment: one line isn't enough, a error will contain a stack, use the try catch block while loading the file, log both error and stack

Answer (score 0):

If you change asset file (create, delete, change name...) you have to stop, clean with `flutter clean` then run again.

Comment: found the error i think application id change when i run this command "flutter-run"

first its says /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4EA1D0AA....

but i debug this its says /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FFD0-4DED...

its always changing why ?

Comment: i think after flutter clean applicationid is change and previous folder removed am i wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. May be /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.. is saved as cache so it create again after flutter clean or each time flutter run.